# Can “tellement” serve as a conjunction, meaning “because ... so much”?

Tags: usage, conjonctions

I mean, when not taking the form of “tellement ... que”?

I want to say:

> Le risotto, c’est l’une de ses spécialités. Quand elle leur en a fait, ses parents sont restés sans voix **tellement** c'était incroyablement délicieux.

I’m not sure if it is correct to use “tellement” in this manner like a conjunction – as a paraphrase of:

> Le risotto, c’est l’une de ses spécialités. Quand elle leur en a fait, c'était **tellement** incroyablement délicieux **que** ses parents sont restés sans voix.

Comment: Both of your sentences are correct, even if mixing *tellement* and *incroyablement* sounds a bit too much, a bit childish.

Comment: A good substitute for "*tellement*" in the first sentence is : "*ses parents sont restés sans voix **tant** c'était délicieux*". And maybe it's just me, but I'd rather say "***il*** *était délicieux*". If you're being general you say "*c'est bon*", but talking about a specific dish it's: "*Bravo pour ton risotto, **il** est délicieux !*"

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Hi. Does this specific use of "tant" belong to a higher register than "tellement"? Also, should I place a comma before "tant/tellement" when they are used this way?

Comment: @Ahalone-zee Yes it's more formal. You don't need to place a comma. By the way, in your second sentence, you can't replace "*tellement*" by "*tant*", the formal version is "*c'était si bon que...*". I'm realizing just now, but I'm pretty sure you can't say "*très délicieux*" (and thus tellement/tant/si) for the same reason you can't say "*very huge*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tellement is already a superlative. If you mix it with incroyablement, you will come off as cheapening the intensity of both words. Try this

> Le risotto est l'une de ses spécialités. Quand elle en a fait à ses parents, ils sont restés sans voix tellement c'était délicieux.

The turn of phrase is more appropriate when spoken than written. In written form, you would remove the split of the second sentence, as such:

> Celui qu'elle a fait à ses parents était tellement délicieux qu'ils sont restés sans voix.

Comment: Why would you change so many details in the sentence? Only *incroyablement* needs to be removed.

Comment: Like I said, even though the first sentence is proper spoken French, it is awkward as written French. Try to reduce split sentences and the use of ce and c' when writing